# Is there a way to pass a username on the header so that an anonymous IIS website will log it in cs-username?

Tags: asp.net, iis

As the title states, I need a way to capture the username on my website so I can find it in the IIS logs.  Now, I know how to pass the username in the header, but because the website uses anonymous authentication, it is not being captured in the log.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: It sounds like you want to involuntarily capture some information about  a user, without prompting the user.  Generally, that is not possible because of security and privacy concerns. However, if the user is on your intranet, that is a different matter.  Are you trying to get this info from intranet users?

Comment: Yes it is on the intranet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on an intranet, you can do this in IIS.   Find your site, choose the IIS "Authentication" config icon, disable Anonymous and enable Windows Authentication.
The authentication will appear seamless to intranet users, as long as they are already authenticated to your domain. If not, it will require authentication (which helps confirm that they are who they say they are).